# An idiom for "on the road"

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

I spend much of my time travelling, and that brings all kinds of challenges.
For example, it can be hard to follow my preferred diet and I don't have access to my books.
How could I express such laments of "life on the road" in Latin?
I could use an idiom that has a similar effect as "on the road".

Are there classical attested phrases for this kind of thing?
For example, Caesar must have "lived out of a suitcase" for quite a while during military campaigns, but did he ever comment on organizing life under those circumstances?
What would be an idiomatic way to express things like "life on the road" or "living out of a suitcase" in classical Latin?

Comment: Are you aware of the adjective [itinerarius](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=itinerarius&la=la&can=itinerarius0&prior=itinerarium#lexicon)? If so, what is it missing for your purpose?

Comment: @Rafael I was not previously aware of that adjective. It looks very promising. Do you happen to know if it was in the kind context I described? Any quote like *o quam difficlis est vita itineraria!* would help prove that it works in the right context. Perhaps I should study the examples in L&S later...